# Loading different data types from text file

Tags: c++, file, loops, types, text-files

I'm new to StackExchange and C++, so apologies if I don't describe the problem well enough. I need some help with homework.
I'm trying to find a way to load this file and store its data. The file has different data types so what I came up with so far was to use struct array to store all the values, using a triple nested for loop to save the data in the correct variable.

Here is what the .dat file looks like, with "comments" to help describe what's going on.

```
100A 2     // model number, 2 different versions of that model

0 0 0      // number of quarters, dimes, and nickels

5          //number of items in the vending machine

1A 1034  5 // Code combonation, ID Number, Quantity

1B 1000 10

1C 1100 10

1D 1123 20

1E 1222  5

0 0 0      // number of quarter, dimes, nickels in 2nd model

7          // number of items in the second version of that model

1A 2180 20

1B 1283 20

1C 3629  5

1D 3649  3

1E 4051 15

1F 4211  1

1G 5318  5

100B 3     // New model, with 3 different versions of itself.

2 10 5     //everything repeats like model 100A

7
```

Here is the code I came up with

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct VMdata
 {
    ifstream inFile;
    string model[1];
    int version[1];
    int q[5];
    int d[5];
    int n[5];
    int size[5];
    string id[30];
    int code[30];
    int num[30];
    char dummy;
};

int main()
{

    VMdata New;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint;

    New.inFile.open("machines.dat");



    cout << "Model Data" 
           << endl   << endl;      



    int count1 = 0;
    int count2= 0;
    int count3 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++)
    {
        cout << "i :" << count1 << endl;
       New.inFile >> New.model[i] >> New.version[i]; // loads model number and number of versions i times
       count1 = count1 + 1;
       for (int j = 0; j < New.version[count1 -1]; j ++)
       {
           cout <<"j :" << count2 << endl;
       New.inFile >> New.q[count2] >> New.d[count2] >> New.n[count2]  >> New.size[count2]; // loads number of q, d, n, j times
       count2 = count2 + 1;
       for (int k = 0; k < New.size[count2 - 1]; k++)
        {
            cout << "k :" << count3 << endl;
           New.inFile >> New.id[count3] >> New.code[count3] >> New.num[count3]; // loads id number, code number, and total number k times
           count3 = count3 + 1;
        }

       }
    }
    New.inFile.close();

     count1 = 0;
    count2= 0;
    count3 = 0;
    cout << endl;

        for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i ++)
    {
       cout << New.model[i]  << setw(12) << New.version[i] << endl << endl;
        count1 = count1 + 1;
       for (int j = 0; j < New.version[count1 -1]; j ++)
       {
       cout << New.q[count2] << setw(12) << New.d[count2] << setw(12) << New.n[count2] << endl << setw(12) << New.size[count2] << endl;
      count2 = count2 + 1;
       for (int k = 0; k < New.size[count2 - 1]; k++)
        {
           cout << New.id[count3] << setw(12) << New.code[count3] << setw(12) << New.num[count3] << endl << endl;
           count3 = count3 + 1;
        }

       }
    }



      return 0;
}
```

Here is my test output.

```
100A           2

3          15           0 // should be 0, 0, 0

 5

1A        1034           5

1B        1000          10

1C        1100          10

1D        1123          20

1E        1222           5

0           0           0

  7

1A        2180          20

1B        1283          20

1C        3629           5

1D        3649           3

1E        4051          15

1F        4211           1

1G        5318           5

♥       ☻            3 // the heart and smile should be 100B lol

2          10           5

  7

1A        2180          10

1B        1283          10

1C        3629           5

1D        3649           3

1E        4051          15

1F        4211          10

1G        3026           5

5           6           3

  6

1A        6626           5

1B        6155           5

1C        5982          10

1D        5573           3

1E        5454          10

1F        5336          50

10          10          10

 5

1A        1034           5

1B        1000           5

1C        1100           5

1D        1123           5

1E        1210          12

Press any key to continue . . .
```

As you can see, the number of quarters, dimes, and nickels is wrong for the first machine, and the model name is wrong for the 2nd model.
If anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

Comment: For this kind of input, I would read the whole line as string then parse it to separated variables (structures).

Comment: Hi Tim, can you give an example of reading a line as string and putting it in different variables? I thought about doing something like this but I was not really sure how to do it, and don't know how to convert string to int. Thank You.

Comment: Sorry i don't have an example  here. Use getline to read the line as string, and use boost::split to split the line into a vector of strings, scan each elements in the vector and convert them to proper type and destination.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are clobbering data.  Your struct allocates only one model and one version, but the i index takes values of 0 and 1.  The second time these are meant to be read in, the address is overwriting your coin counts.